# MacBook crashing whenever I try to do something

Tags: macos, disk-utility, ssd, crash

I changed my MacBook Air 2017's SSD to a third-party one, so I tried to install macOS on it using a USB boot key but whenever I try do something with the disk like installing Monterey or erasing disk, it crashes.

Video: https://youtu.be/kfgy5rEdDD0

Comment: Presumably you are using an M2 Adaptor? Are you sure that the drive will work with your Mac?

Comment: Yes, I am using an adaptator. Honestly, I don't know and can't know I think. If it was not compatible at all, it might say something like "Incorrect drive" I think.

Comment: You could try to out your old disk in a usb adaptator and then boot on it. Then initialise new ssd and install macOS on the newly installed ssd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSD was not compatible with this MacBook. I switched over to a Crucial P2 and it worked just fine.

Comment: What was the make and model of the incompatible SSD?

Comment: I don't remember well, it was quite a bit time ago. But from what I remember it was a Samsung SSD but not a regular one. I saw that the EVO 970 works with MacBooks.